# Finding parent context in a Blaze.TemplateInstance

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a simple table and each row has 2 columns: a name and a boolean. The `busStopId` and `selected` fields are inherited from the `{{#each}}` block in the parent context, as shown:

```
<template name="selectionTable">
    ...
    {{#each busStops}}
      {{>selectDoc doc}}
    {{/each}}
    ...
</template>

<template name="selectDoc">
  <tr>
    <td>{{getName ../busStopId}}</td>
    <td>{{../selected}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

When I hover over `tr`, I'd like to get the `busStopId` used to compute that particular row. My problem is that I can't find it in the template context. I know all the parent data lives in `template.parent().data`, but I need the data specifically for the row I'm hovering over.I imagine it'd look something like this:

```
Template.selectDoc.events({
  'mouseenter tr': function (event,template) {
    console.log(template.?data?.busStopId);
  }
});
```

Hopefully someone smarter than me can fill in the `?data?` part or offer a workaround (worst case scenario I can include the `busStopId` in the DOM & grab it from the `event`, but I'd prefer to learn how to do it the right way).

Comment: At the moment, I think your only choice is to use `this` or `template` in the event handler or [Template.parentData](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata) to access data contexts. If none of them can grab the context you're looking for, I'm afraid you can't achieve what you want. But I think MDG is working on improving this.

Answer (score 0):

For others battling with this seemingly simple problem, here's my solution:

```
Template.selectDoc.helpers({
  name: function(busStopId) {
    Template.instance().busStopId = busStopId;
    return BusStops.findOne(busStopId).name;
  }
});

Template.selectDoc.events({
  'mouseenter tr': function (e, template) {
    console.log(template.busStopId);
  }
});
```

As shown, I manually attach the `busStopId` to the template inside the helper. Then, I pull it out from the template in the event. Still hacky, but it keeps my HTML clean.

Ideally, I think it'd be great to have an `{{#each}}` index saved to the template so I could use that to grab directly from the `.parent().data`, but in the mean time 2 lines isn't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case storing the id as a data attribute on the DOM element is perfectly fine.

Here is a working Meteor Pad example : 
http://meteorpad.com/pad/RbwwTvMugycM5zYLg/Using%20data-attr%20to%20store%20values

This is the code :

```
<template name="leaderboard">
  <ol class="leaderboard">
    {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
    {{/each}}
  </ol>

  Their score : 
  <div id="score"></div>
</template>

<template name="player">
  <div id='{{_id}}' data-score='{{score}}' class='player'>
  {{name}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.player.events({
  'mouseover div': function (e) {
    $('#score').html( $(e.target).attr('data-score') );
  }
});
```

Why do you feel it's not a good solution to store attributes in the dom like this?  I use it all the time.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that's been my pattern, too, I'm just looking for a new way. I felt like I was cluttering up the HTML with all these custom attributes that can be taken care of behind the scenes.